# Loading content dynamically from database using Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

So I'm new to Ajax, this is my first attempt at using it, hoping that someone can help me find my mistake. The goal is that I have a list of vehicle styles and in the database, I have Makes associated with specific styles. So when a radio button with a style is selected, it should populate a dropdown list with the Makes associated.

I got it working well on Chrome, but having issues with other browser such as IE and Safari.

Screen shot of it working on Chrome here: [Link](http://www.screencast.com/t/ARKrXoyw)

Screen shot of it not working on Safari here: [Link](http://www.screencast.com/t/8TiDjtljB0)

The form name is: autoForm
And the radio fields have an onclick event to call getMakes().

This is my function:

```
function getMakes() {
       $.post('getMake.php', {
            vehicleStyle: autoForm.style.value
        },
        function(output) {
               $('#vehicle-makes').hide();
            $('#vehicle-makes').html(output).slideDown("slow");
        });
}
```

Here is the PHP from getMake.php

```
PDO/database stuff up here^^ Leaving it out of the example
$list = '<label for="vehicle_make">Makes</label>
              <select name="vehicle_make"
                    class="form-control"
                    onchange="getModels()">
                    <option value="">Select One</option>';

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $list .= '<option value="'.$result->make.'">'.$result->make.'</option>';
    }

    $list .= '</select>';

    echo $list;
```

So as you can see, it is communicating with the getMakes.php because it's bringing over the empty dropdown list - but it looks like it's not sending the data over to the PHP to pull associated data from the DB.

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you test this fiddle code in safari and let me know is it working, if it is not working try to change the name of style to some other which is not a keyword.. like name or something and try again and let us know  https://jsfiddle.net/naveencgr/9tqgs4t6/

Comment: I do get the alert of test in safari, yes.

Comment: Check below things to make sure where exactly it is failing in safari          1. Can you check in the network tab of the browser to see if the data is passing with url or not                                                                                                       2. echo the value of vehicleStyle in the php page and see you are getting it correct

Comment: Yeah so this is going along with what I've been thinking the problem is. In the php file, all I am doing right now is echoing out the value of the $_POST['vehicleStyle'] - in Chrome, it's displaying the value. In Safari and IE, it is not. So for some reason, it's not sending over that value.

Comment: What I did now, in PHP, I am echoing out this: echo '<script>alert("test");</script>';   and I do get the alert in Safari and IE as well as Chrome. So it is accessing that getMakes.php page for sure, it's just not sending the data over.

Comment: One more follow up, I change this piece of code: $.post('inc/ajax/getMake.php', {
            vehicleStyle: 'test'
        },  

Now it does display the word test. So the issue is with: dmrForm.config_style.value

Comment: can you add your html form

Comment: @user3498863, thank you for you help, your suggestions really pointed me in the right direction and I was able to solve the issue. It turned out to be the way that Safari and IE pass values through JS/Jquery. I went with this and it works:   

var $data = $("input[name=style]:checked").val();
       $.post('getMake.php', {
            vehicleStyle: $data
        },

Comment: Vote for my comment if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

So what I figured out is that this doesn't work in IE and Safari:

vehicleStyle: autoForm.style.value

I had to get the value of the input differently, and it worked.